# List all cronjobs if there are any without superfluous info

Tags: bash, filter, grep, cron

Trying to output a list of cronjobs, not a list of users. The raw output of `crontab -l` is way too dirty and I can't seem to clean it up. I run this with `sudo script.sh` or `su` and then run it. I've tried invoking it `sudo script.sh | grep -v no` also. I'm mystified why this doesn't work:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#Trying to show all cronjobs but no extraneous info
#
# This shows "no crontab for USER" for every USER without
# a crontab - I only want to see actual cronjobs, not a long
# list of users without crontabs
echo "Here is the basic output that needs manipulation:
"
for USER in `cat /etc/passwd | cut -d":" -f1`; do
    crontab -l -u $USER
done
#
# grep -v fails me
# (grep'ing the output of the script as a whole fails also)
echo "
trying with grep -v no on each line:
"
for USER in `cat /etc/passwd | cut -d":" -f1`; do
    crontab -l -u $USER | grep -v no
done

echo "
maybe with quotes around the no:
"
for USER in `cat /etc/passwd | cut -d":" -f1`; do
    crontab -l -u $USER | grep -v "no"
done

# string manipulation - I can't even get started
echo "
And here I try to put the commmand output into a string so I can   manipulate it further, and use an if/then/fi on the product:
"
for USER in `cat /etc/passwd | cut -d":" -f1`; do
    STRING="$(crontab -l -u $USER | grep -v no)"
    echo "STRING: $STRING"
done
```

BTW, is there an easier way to get code to format correctly here than pasting in 4 spaces at the beginning of each line? I must have experimented for 40 minutes. Not complaining, just asking.

Comment: Select (paint) the entire code block and hit ctrl-K to format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

crontab is wiring the "no crontab for user" to standard error. To get rid of those messages, you can run

```
crontab -l -u $USER 2>/dev/null
```

within your loop.

I would also suggest renaming `USER` into something else. The `USER` variable name is reserved, and should be set to your user (login) name.  Generally, you should use lower case variable names, to avoid this sort of name clash.

Comment: Thanks - error, not output, that's it. I verified it both by adding the error redirection, which works for the script, and just to be OCD about it, by echoing $?. The use of the variable USER isn't a problem, and, in the for loop context it's in, it should catch cronjobs for ALL users, which was my intent. I clicked the checkmark, but I didn't see anything happen. I'll check again later.

Comment: I'd edit my prior comment if I could.  On rereading I understand what you mean about the variable name. Good tip, thanks.